# How to force angular to use jqlite or manually reference the jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm stuck with an incompatible version of jQuery in my Angular app, I can't upgrade jQuery but can load the latest jQuery version side by side using the noConflict method but I cant seem to find a way to force Angular.js to use the newer jQuery version. Is there such a method available?

**Flow**:

```
<head>
    <script src="jQuery 1.3.2">
    <script src="old jquery code">
</head>

<body>
    …

    <script src="jQuery 1.10.2"/>
        <script>
            var newjquery = jQuery.noConflict();
        </script>

        <script src="angular.js"/>

        <script>
            // angular code
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post some code samples of how the individual script files of both angular and jQuery are included?

Comment: why cant you upgrade your jquery? or remove the old one?

Comment: I'm working on a big Drupal 6 project which comes bundled with jQuery 1.3.2, upgrading breaks a lot of things.

Comment: As I updated my answer with the code example I got it working by placing the jQuery.noConflict after loading the newer version instead of placing it after the old version. Now everything seems to be working fine. The code in my question works.

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery *if
> it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped*.
> If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to
> its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

Try to change the position in which you import the scripts:

- new jquery
- angular
- older jquery

I am not sure it would work, but from my understanding Angular should use the already present jQuery.

Comment: This actually works. I was working on a project on a hosted "platform" and Angular was throwing errors because the jQuery was too old. I was able to load Angular before the old jQuery and this fixed my problem. Simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the new directive `ng-jq` with angular 1.4.x to set the Version of switch to jQLite (angular internal jQuery)