# Configure AngularJS to ignore old version of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular to add a new feature to an old site that loads a very old version of jQuery.

How can I check if Angular is using that jQuery version? And if it uses the old jQuery version, how could I configure Angular to ignore it and fallback to jqLite?

I am finding some random errors and I would like to rule an incompatibility out before digging any further.

Comment: you may refer to this SO for answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900291/prevent-angularjs-from-using-jquery-library

Comment: seems to be a fair question and somebody has voted to close...^^??

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to that question. I did not find it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should let you know the version of jQuery used by angular:

`angular.element.fn.jquery`

Which should be the same as

`$.fn.jquery`

Which will give you the version of jQuery loaded in the page.

You can revert to jQlite by removing jQuery from the page, but I'm not sure you can easily do it while keeping jQuery on the page as jQlite is private in angular's script. You could edit angular.js to save a reference of jQlite in the global scope, but then you can't use minified angular.

Another option is to include a script with [jQlite's source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js) on the page, then use it with `angular.element = window.JQLite`. Overall though, just removing jQuery from the page would be your best bet, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, `$.fn.jquery` returns my jQuery version. `angular.element.fn` is undefined.

Does it mean angular is not loading jQuery. I didn't change anything yet. Removing jQuery is not possible as my angular feature is embeded in a page which needs the original jQuery.

Comment: @Esclapes Hmm, it seems that if you include the jQuery script after angular it doesn't use it. I was always under the impression the angular script covers this case. You could try that.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Both scripts are loaded in the head, but jQuery loads later. Thanks for your reply about how to get the version of jQuery.